# Copying the connection roles from lead to contact and account

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

D365 online - copying connection roles, which are present on lead record to contact and account when user qualifies the lead? Is there a no code solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRM internally using inbuilt plugin to create connections on qualify lead flow. That means CRM itself uses code to create Connections using connection Roles.

So there is **no** *no-code* solution possible to cascade the connection between entities unless some managed solution does it in market.

Reference: [Blog link](http://www.microsoftcrmblog.com/2015/05/lead-not-able-to-qualify-in-microsoft.html?m=1)

> when you qualify the Lead, a new Contact and a new Opportunity is created and also connections between these new records are created. The new connection records use a stakeholder role.

Reference: [Blog link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/choruscrmblog/archive/2015/09/30/never-delete-your-stakeholder-connection-role)

> The plugin in question is responsible for, after the contact has be created by the lead qualification, creating a connection between the opportunity and the contact with the role of stake holder.
>
> the plugin has the guid of the role hard coded into it. Even more fortunate is that this guid is standard across all Dynamics CRM deployments.

Comment: I am aware of this, CRM is not carrying the connections from Lead to Contact.